# mysql Query With Two Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables

```
Table TblParts
(id
detail
code
stock)


Table TblExistencias
(code
Serial)
```

I need to make a query to upgrade `TblParts.stock` with `TblExistencias` Table (Counting Code).

```
if TblExistencias.code = TblParts.code then Count(TblExistencias.code) and update TblParts.stock
```

How can I make it?

Comment: Eric. I dont know how can i make it.

Answer (score 2):

You should do something like this. 
Update statement with sub query

```
update TblParts set stock= COALESCE((select count(*) from TblExistencias where 
TblExistencias.code = TblParts.code),0)
```

Comment: Thanks!, Works Good!

Comment: if it has helped you, please accept the answer as accepted.

Comment: Thanks For Response, Both querys Works if i have TblExistencias.codigo, But if i dont have TblExistencias.codigo i need update TblPartes.stock = 0 too

Comment: Updated my answer. USe the coalesce function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null

Answer (score 0):

You should get the count for stock from TblExistencias by joining TblParts and TblExistencias on code.
Like,

```
select TE.CODE,COUNT(TE.CODE) AS COUNT
FROM TblParts TP
inner JOIN TblExistencias as TE ON TP.CODE=TE.CODE
GROUP BY TE.CODE
```

Use above query as subquery on your update query , alias the result from above query as X and use it with update query . so your update query will be

```
UPDATE TblParts as t
set stock=X.COUNT
from 
(select TE.CODE,COUNT(TE.CODE) AS COUNT
FROM TblParts TP
inner JOIN TblExistencias as TE ON TP.CODE=TE.CODE
GROUP BY TE.CODE
) AS X
 where t.CODE=X.CODE;
```

Comment: Thanks For Response, Both querys Works if i have TblExistencias.codigo, But if i dont have TblExistencias.codigo i need update TblPartes.stock = 0 too

select TE.codigo,COUNT(TE.codigo) AS COUNT
FROM TblPartes TP
left JOIN TblExistencias as TE ON TP.codigo1=TE.codigo
GROUP BY TE.codigo

Comment: The query you sent me Return Error Too.

Comment: with inner join it worked fine i have checked on postgressql as it was handy to me. for left join count(TE.CODE) should manipulate to show it as 0 as per your database synatx. in mysql 'CASE WHEN' will work. try it othewise once i try it in mysql will revert.